# Compare images with JS

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a site and there will be an image in the background with the following dimensions: `100vw, 100vh` – But of course I want the page to be **responsive** and this is my plan:

It is ok, to distort this background-image a bit, but I should never be distorted to much, so I want to create **multiple different images**, for different aspect-ratios and sizes and whenever the page is being loaded, or resized, I would like to have a script that looks at the `viewport: aspect-ratio and size`, then looks at all the images and finds the one that is most similar to the viewport and then sets that image as the background-images of: `div class="bg-overlay"`

This is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="bg-overlay"></div>
```

CSS:

```
bg-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    
    background-image: url("resources/Test-Screens/RZ_BG_1920x1080_16-9.png");
    background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}
```

JS:

```
var bgOverlayDiv = document.querySelector(".bg-overlay");

// Image-Library START
var bg_1280x720 = {
    name: 'RZ_BG_1280x720_16-9.png',
    width: '1280',
    height: '720'
};
bg_1280x720.ratio = bg_1280x720.width / bg_1280x720.height;

var bg_1920x1080 = {
    name: 'RZ_BG_1920x1080_16-9.png',
    width: '1920',
    height: '1080'
};
bg_1920x1080.ratio = bg_1920x1080.width / bg_1920x1080.height;

var bg_3840x2160 = {
    name: 'RZ_BG_3840x2160_16-9.png',
    width: '3840',
    height: '2160'
};
bg_3840x2160.ratio = bg_3840x2160.width / bg_3840x2160.height;

var bg_4000x4000 = {
    name: 'RZ_BG_4000x4000_1-1.png',
    width: '4000',
    height: '4000'
};
bg_4000x4000.ratio = bg_4000x4000.width / bg_4000x4000.height;

var bg_2000x2000 = {
    name: 'RZ_BG_2000x2000_1-1.png',
    width: '2000',
    height: '2000'
};
bg_2000x2000.ratio = bg_2000x2000.width / bg_2000x2000.height;

var bg_1000x1000 = {
    name: 'RZ_BG_1000x1000_1-1.png',
    width: '1000',
    height: '1000'
};
bg_1000x1000.ratio = bg_1000x1000.width / bg_1000x1000.height;

var bg_1080x1920 = {
    name: 'RZ_BG_1080x1920_9-16.png',
    width: '1080',
    height: '1920'
};
bg_1080x1920.ratio = bg_1080x1920.width / bg_1080x1920.height;
// Image-Library END

var viewportRatio = undefined;
var chosenImage = undefined;

function changeBgOverlay() {    
    // Calculate viewport aspect-ratio. START
    viewportRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    console.log(viewportRatio);
    // Calculate viewport aspect-ratio. END

    chosenImage = bg_1080x1920; // Add: Choose most suitable image.
    
    bgOverlayDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url('resources/Test-Screens/" + chosenImage.name + "')";
}

changeBgOverlay();
window.addEventListener('resize', changeBgOverlay);
```

^- I can't really share a fiddle, because there are images involved, I hope it's clear what this script is doing, if not, please tell me, I can also just send someone the folder-structure that I have on my computer, with all the images, but **this is basically what's happening right now**:

First I'm creating multiple objects for every image in my folder-structure, these objects have properties: `name, width, height, (aspact-)ratio` – Then I calculate the viewport-aspect-ratio (`var viewportRatio`) – Then there is a line that, right now, says: `chosenImage = bg_1080x1920;` (This is where the script should look for the most suitable image, right now, I'm just manually telling it to use the object called: `bg_1080x1920`) – Then it replaces the image.

Screenshot of the folder containing the images: [image: screenshot]

I already played around with this for a while, but I don't really now how to do this, I would very much appreciate any sort of input. Thank You! – Simon

Comment: If you base it on width of the screen/viewport then why not use CSS media queries. No JavaScript required!

Comment: Because it's not just about width, but also aspect-ratio, example: 1080x1920 and 1080x720 have the same width.

Comment: What if I'm browsing on a mobile in portrait? the aspect ratio would be way off?

Comment: What happens if I resize browser window and there isn't a good fit?

Comment: There will be an appropriate fit because there will be multiple images for different aspect-rations and sizes. These files from the screenshot, that's just what I'm using for testing right now.

Comment: Also, CSS Media Queries can use more than just the width... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Media_features

Comment: Ok, I'm looking into this, thank you!