# Comparing multiple properties, of multiple objects

Tags: javascript

This is a visualization of my problem:
[image]

–––––––––––––––––––––

I have a variable called: `viewport`, this variable has multiple properties: **width, height, ratio;** – Then I have some more variables: `obj1, obj2, obj3, …` – I need a script that looks at all the variables and then outputs the **name of the variable** that is **most similar to** `viewport`.

–––––––––––––––––––––

The most important property is the **ratio**, so the script should first look at the **ratio: value**. – In the example above it would see that `obj1` and `obj2` are most similar to `viewport` because they both have a ratio of: 1.7. – Next the script should look at `obj1` and `obj2` and ask: What object is most similar to `viewport` in terms of width? In the example the script would see, that `obj1` ist closest to `viewport` and so would spit out to me: `obj1`

*I already played around with this for a while, but I'm not that experienced in JS and I can't get it to work. I would very much appreciate any sort of input. Thank You! –Simon*

Edit: (See comments.)
[image]

Comment: Please post the code that you played around with. It's quite unclear where you have a problem - is it about writing such a function (taking an object and an array of objects) in the first place, or is it the ambiguous definition of "similarity"?

Comment: @Bergi This is actually the second time that I post this question, the first time I posted more code, but I didn't get any answers and I thought it's because there was so much code and nobody wanted to read all that. This is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65493343/compare-images-with-js I hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: The only line in that code that's relevant to the algorithm you want is "*`chosenImage = bg_1080x1920; // Add: Choose most suitable image.`*", and there's nothing there yet.

Comment: Yes, because I don't know how to write that code… Sorry, I now see, this might not have been totally clear, but that is my problem.

Comment: `[obj1, obj2, obj3].map(({ ratio: r, width: w, height: h, name }) => ({ r: Math.abs(viewport.ratio - r), w: Math.abs(viewport.width - w), h: Math.abs(viewport.height - h), name })).reduce((p, c) => (p.r - c.r || p.w - c.w || p.h - c.h) < 0 ? p : c).name` this assumes objects have a `name` property, similar to your other question. I only renamed the variables to make them shorter in a comment, no real need to.

Comment: @Bergi Do you maybe have an idea, on how I could do this?  Doesn't have to be code, a rough outline would already help, or maybe something I should google, that will help me solve this…

Comment: @ASDFGerte Hey, cool! I will incorporate this into my code shortly and I will let you know, if it worked. :)

Comment: @ASDFGerte Sorry, if this is a stupid question, but where does this script output the name of the chosen variable? – In the end, is there only one variable left in the array and how can I grab that? Thank you!

Comment: It's just a snippet, there was no explicit structure given to use. It assumes `obj1` etc have `ratio`, `width`, `height`, and `name` properties. It first maps it to the absolute difference between the respective properties and the `viewport`'s same property, and then runs over the array, always picking the "closest", giving one element at the end (which is not the same as the input objects, because of the previous mapping step, but still has the `name` dragged through), and then selects that `name` with `.name`.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Hey Man, I don't wanna waste your time, but I just don't understand this, this is what I have right now: we.tl/t-kbsXUktA1H (link)

Comment: I won't download any files, sorry.

Comment: There's nothing weird in there, but I totally get that, give me a sec…

Comment: All the test images that I have created, of course, are missing here, but this is all the code: jsfiddle.net/qhz6foLx/

Comment: @ASDFGerte I have also added a picture of my folder-structure to the question.

Comment: the entire thing is an expression, you can do whatever you want with it, e.g. just prepend a `let chosenImage = ` or wrap it in a `console.log( /* stuff here */ );`, or whatever.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226617/discussion-between-simon-r-and-asdfgerte).

Answer (score 0):

I changed properties to show a good use case. also, consider a **name or identity** for objects (here i used id property).

```js
var viewport = { width: 2000, height: 1000, ratio: 3 };
var obj1 = { id: '#1', width: 1920, height: 1080, ratio: 1.7 };
var obj2 = { id: '#2', width: 1280, height: 720, ratio: 3 };
var obj3 = { id: '#3', width: 2000, height: 1000, ratio: 1 };

function customSortByProperties(baseViewport, otherViewports) {
    let matches = {};
    otherViewports.forEach((obj) => {
        matches[obj.id] = 0;
        for (let property in obj) {
            if (baseViewport[property] === obj[property]) {
                if (property === 'ratio') {
                    matches[obj.id] += 2;
                } else {
                    matches[obj.id] += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return Object.keys(matches).sort((a, b) => { return matches[b] - matches[a] });
}

console.log(customSortByProperties(viewport, [obj1, obj2, obj3]));
```

You need an array instead of a single result because maybe there are two items with the same **match count**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will incorporate this into my code and I will let you know, if it worked. :)

Comment: I actually, kind of, need one result, could you take a look at this code: jsfiddle.net/Lmq07cvk/ – I think this would make things more clear.

Comment: you can do like this: const sortedMatches = customSortByProperties(viewport, [obj1, obj2, obj3]); const result = sortedMatches.length > 0 ? sortedMatches[0] : null;

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand, again, I don't have a lot of experience with JS. I have a variable called: `chosenImage`, when, for example, chosenImage = obj3, the respective image is selected, how do I get the result into the chosenImage-variable?

Comment: this is about programming and not javascript. add this code to my last comment: chosenImage = result